Command for ignoring all upcoming lines in tex
I know % can ignore a certain line or paragraph of tex document. Suppose I have a document
\begin{document}
para1
para2

para3
etc...
\end{document}

If I use % sign in para 1 as "%para1" it only ignores para1. I want to know if there is a way by which a Latex can ignore all upcoming line/paragraphs.
Thanks.

\end{document}.

why  is this tagged [tag:biblatex]

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain, why you want to do this? Could be an X-Y-problem ...

This is what the comment environment (part of the comment package) is designed to do.

This seems to work; stops after the third paragraph:
\documentclass{article}

% define the paragraph after which to stop
\newcommand\stopAfterPar{3}

\newcount\myParCnt
\def\forcedEnd{\fi\end{document}}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \everypar{%
    \advance\myParCnt by 1
    \ifnum\myParCnt>\stopAfterPar\endgroup\forcedEnd\fi
  }
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}


Not sure if this is what you want, but you can enclose any portion of code between \iffalse and \fi to ignore.

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
para1

para2

\iffalse
para3

para4 
\fi

para5

\end{document}

